# Any change for Azure API (esp: Azure storage account) with TLS 1.2

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, tls1.2

We have the Azure storage account that has a minimum TLS 1.0.

We are downloading the zip file from Blob container using Powershell + SAS key. We are running it from Windows Server 2016. It was working fine until last Friday (22/10/2021).

Now, we are getting "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.”".

We have to enable TLS 1.2 to download the zip file. So I am looking for the root cause. I am wondering if Microsoft depreciated the old version of TLS on Azure API or storage account or even on Windows. Does anyone have the same issue? I couldn't find any new about TLS depreciation on 22/20/2021 too.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Azure updates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?category=storage&query=TLS) page , we don't have any communication/updates about the deprecation of TLS 1.0 for the storage account API .

According to this  [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/transport-layer-security-configure-minimum-version?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json&tabs=portal) , Azure Storage currently supports three versions of the TLS protocol: 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2. Azure Storage uses TLS 1.2 on public HTTPS endpoints, but TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 are still supported for backward compatibility.

**Configure the [minimum TLS version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/transport-layer-security-configure-minimum-version?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json&tabs=portal#configure-the-minimum-tls-version-for-a-storage-account) for a storage account:**

The default value of the  **MinimumTlsVersion**  property is different depending on how you set it. When you create a storage account with the Azure portal, the minimum TLS version is set to 1.2 by default. When you create a storage account with PowerShell, Azure CLI, or an Azure Resource Manager template, the  **MinimumTlsVersion**  property is not set by default and does not return a value until you explicitly set it.

When the  **MinimumTlsVersion**  property is not set, its value may be displayed as either  **null**  or an empty string, depending on the context. The storage account will permit requests sent with TLS version 1.0 or greater if the property is not set.

For More information ,We would suggest you to open a discussion in [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html)  or to file a technical support ticket by following the [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) where technical support team would help you in troubleshooting the issue from platform end.